# jenkins from master running multiple downstream jobs

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration

use case: I want to run the regression suite on multiple images(image selection is variable it can be 4 or 5).

I want to create 1 master job who will take the images name as an input, and This master job passes the image name one by one to downstream regression job. The number of images can be variable.

```
                          Master job
             INPUT image: a,b,c .....
                              |
                              |
      -------------------------------------------------
      |                       |                        |
   Regression job           Regression              REgression
  Input image: a            Image b                 Image c
```

Can anyone just tell me how can I perform this task in Jenkins?

To Solve this, I have used the pipeline and Active choice parameter plugins.

Here is the configuration:

[image: Active choice parameter]

[image: pipeline plugin configuration]

Here is the problem, I am getting ThunderImage list as [p,1,p,2,p,3] instead of ['p1','p2','p3'] .

Answer (score 0):

So,you want to select which regression Job starts depending on the selected input from your Master Job? For this you could use the [Post build task](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Post+build+task) and use it's regex functionality to check for the input Paramter inside the Build Log.

If you are using a Pipeline job you can use the solution of Christopher Orr from: [Jenkins trigger build dependent on build parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35344304/jenkins-trigger-build-dependent-on-build-parameters)